# How to migrate Redis database to Aerospike?

Tags: redis, aerospike

We have a large redis database. The number of keys exploded recently as we have ~160M keys which take 50GB+ of RAM.

What would be the best migration strategy to move all this data from Redis to Aerospike? We are planning to use Jedis later so hopefully after the migration it will be as simple as pointing our services to a new port.

Ideally we can somehow import the `dump.rdb` file into Aerospike.

Comment: Check this guide on aerospike.com http://www.aerospike.com/blog/redis-operations-in-aerospike/  some aerospike community users also have additional solutions: https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/moving-data-from-redis-to-aerospike-how-to-generate-digest-string-as-in-backup-file-format/876

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put a little bit of extra work. Aerospike now supports Redis like list and map APIs. So, the migration will not be painful. However, you need to migrate your data and application.

To migrate data, you can export Redis data in csv format using the `redis-cli` utility and load it into aerospike using the [aerospike csv loader](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-loader) utility. You can parallelize the loading if you split the data into multiple csv files.

To migrate the application, it's best to use aerospike native client library for better integration. You can pick language of your choice. You should find equivalent api for most of your needs. If you already abstracted the basic calls in your application, the migration should be even more smoother as there will be few places where you need to change the calls.